# How do I turn a listbox into a string array in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

I'm working on a project where I have to pass a receipt between windows, how would i turn the listbox into a string array to pass it to another window? Or is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: ListBox.Items.ToArray() or better to use the Binding source from ViewModel.

Comment: Work with the base data rather than ui.

Comment: @Das, Is any update?  Please check if the following answers works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your description, you want to convert your listbox to a string array and pass it to another window.

You can try the following code.

MainWindow:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Mon");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Tue");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Wed");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Thu");
            listBox1.Items.Add("Fri");
        }
        public string[] result { get; set; }
        private void btntest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
            result = list.ToArray();
            Window1 window = new Window1();
            window.Show();
            
        }
```

Window1:

```
 public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox2.ItemsSource = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).result;
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a WPF Listbox like this

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="200">
    <ListBoxItem  Content="aa"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="bb"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="cc"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="dd"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="ee"></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="ff"/>
</ListBox>
```

You can get the items in string[] using Linq as follows

```
ItemCollection i1 = listBox1.Items;
string[] s1 = i1.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Select(x => (string)x.Content).ToArray();
```

That's it.